# Shape=ring in android not displaying

Tags: android, android-shape

I am trying to display some text in a coloured circle, but it is not working properly. This is how I am rendering the text -

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GO"
    android:background="@drawable/scancircle"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="18dp"
    android:padding="9dp"
    android:onClick="Go"
    />
```

And this is how `scancircle.xml` looks like -

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="ring"
    android:innerRadius="93dp"
    android:thickness="1dp"
    android:useLevel="false"
    >
    <solid android:color="@color/primary" />
    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="@color/txtVwBackground"
        />

    <padding
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Even though the preview of scancircle shows the circle correctly, but there is no circle rendered behind the text. Can anyone tell why is this so?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you see? I would say that right now there should be a big circle behind the textview - much larger than the view itself and perhaps not looking like a circle.

Comment: It doesn't show anything, just the text. The circle is of dark blue color and shows up on preview on scancircle.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, actually you don't use *circle*, you use a *ring*, which has a hole in the middle. In your case this hole is of 93dp radius that makes it bigger than the `TextView` itself. Thus what you see behind the text is the hole part of the ring, which is transparent.

You may want to use [`oval`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) shape for the "circle behind the text" effect.